# Show Disrespect/Poor Behavior

Tags: grammar, word-usage

The first sentence is good English:

1. "The students ***showed disrespect*** toward the teacher."
2. "The students ***showed poor behavior*** toward the teacher."

Is the second sentence also good?

Answer (score 1):

The first is correct grammar.

The second is more complicated than it seems at first sight.

If you mean that their poor behaviour was specifically directed at the teacher, then you would need to say: 'The students behaved badly toward the teacher'.

But if, as I suspect, you mean that their behaviour was generally bad, whilst in the company of the teacher, then you would need to say  'The students behaved badly whilst with the teacher'.

Whilst one can 'show disrespect' one does not normally 'show poor behavior toward' someone. One does 'behave badly toward them' though. But as indicated I doubt this is what is meant.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the second sentence is perfectly fine idiomatic English. I might use 'towards' rather than 'toward', but both are correct. Supposedly, U.S. English tends more towards 'toward'.

Comment: So, this would work too:  "The students ***showed misbehavior*** toward the teacher."

Comment: I disagree with this answer. Whilst 1. is perfectly correct grammar, 2.is not.

Comment: @WS2 Do you disagree that it is idomatic English? Or just that it is "correct" in a prescriptivist sense?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany 'The students showed poor behaviour towards the teacher' is clumsy and something I would not expect to hear a native speaker say. As indicated in my answer there are two possible meanings. But in my view that sentence does not do justice to either of them.